# How can I add dlib in cmake with findpackage?

Tags: cmake, dlib, cmake-gui

This is my cmakelists.txt:

```
project( WolframMachine )                                    
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION true)
include(ExternalProject)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/boost_1_66_0")
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "C:/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.0")
SET("OpenCV_DIR" "C:/opencv-3.4.1/build")
SET(dlib_DIR "C:/dlib-19.13/")  # <============ DLIB
find_package( OpenCV COMPONENTS core imgproc highgui aruco optflow plot REQUIRED )
find_package(dlib REQUIRED)  # <============ DLIB
add_subdirectory(dlibtest)
```

Running cmake-gui gives me following:

[image]

setting dlib_DIR manually doesn't help. How can I fix this?

**UPD**: tried other dlib_DIR values with no success:

```
SET(dlib_DIR "C:/dlib-19.13/build/dlib/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/cmake/dlib")
```

gives same error:

[image]

and setting

```
SET(dlib_DIR "C:/dlib-19.13/build/dlib/config")
```

gives another meaningless error:

[image]

Comment: `setting dlib_DIR manually doesn't help.` - Set `dlib_DIR` variable to the directory, containing `dlibConfig.cmake` file. Directory probably ends with `cmake/dlib`.

Comment: setting dlib to that folder gives another error

Comment: Which error it gives?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, please see my update.

Comment: 1) What are the contents of dlib_DIR?  The actual file contents, not the path.  2) Please include your errors as text, not as images.

Comment: It smells like you have just *built*, but have not **installed** dlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like dlib was not designed to add it with find_package. What you have to do is to add it as subdirectory:

```
add_subdirectory(C:/dlib-19.13 dlib_build)
```

and also add resulting libs to your binary:

```
target_link_libraries( ${CUR_PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} dlib::dlib)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: DLib works fine with `find_package`. We use it in our project and it works fine. Our `CMakeLists.txt` contains the following 3 lines: `find_package(DLIB REQUIRED)`, `include_directories(${DLIB_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY})`, `target_link_libraries(your_project ${DLIB_LIBRARIES} dlib)`.

Comment: This solution suggested by Dlib and used in examples/CMakeLists.txt. The only problem is whenever you clean your project, Dlib will be cleaned also and it should be compiled again!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I followered,

For installing the dlib, change the link to the desired version

```
wget http://dlib.net/files/dlib-19.6.tar.bz2 
tar xvf dlib-19.6.tar.bz2
cd dlib-19.6/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

In your project,

```
find_package(dlib REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(try_convex  dlib::dlib)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these in top level CMakeLists.txt?

```
SET(dlib_ROOT "C:/dlib-19.13/")
```

or

```
SET(dlib_DIR "C:/dlib-19.13/" CACHE STRING "")
```

Comment: Setting the dlib path manually is really not the correct way. If dlib was installed correctly, cmake would find it. If you are using Windows: MSYS2 supports dlib + cmake out of the box.